# Google Analytics eCommerce Tracking configuration

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, analytics

I have implemented eCommerce tracking on below domain but it seems nothing is recording so far. If anyone can check this and let me know what has gone wrong, it would be much helpful.

http://www.champacentralhotel.com/

Thanks

Comment: When have you implemented it?
I see a Google Analytics Code an a Remarketing Code. Both working fine.

Comment: You'll need to do more on your part than just having others inspect your code. Please try debugging it yourself and if you have any code issues/questions, then post them here.

Comment: Dear @nyuen I have tried to make to it work even after changing the code few times. I'm not sure this happens from the booking engine end as i dont have access for booking engine which i send the codes them to be implemented. and also im not an expert in analytics so I did all these by going through the analytics guide. it woudl be great of you can help me out

Comment: Dear @MFGSparka I did implement this 4-5 days back. I did couple of test bookings but nothing has been recorded even though the tags has been fired in booking confirmation

Comment: Have you tryed the google chrome plugin (tag assistant)? 
And you don't filter your own ip-adress? Trya it from a different mashine